# Google analytics set custom variable that change value after contact form submission Drupal 7

Tags: php, google-analytics, drupal-7

My purpuse is to get the categories' statistics of contact requests sent by users by submiting the site contact form.
I'm working with the Drupal-7 contributive module  "google analytics" and I think about setting a custom variable called "contact form category" that change value according to  to the choosen contact form category  of one visitor

I guess I should begin with the following code

```
$('#contact-site-form').submit(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact Form', 'Form submission', 'New submission']);
});
```

Please, can you help me to find the solution :(

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using google analytics classic by the usage of _gaq, I strongly advise you to upgrade to universal analytics.

In universal analytics, Custom variables are deprecated. You should use custom dimensions or metrics instead. They're practically the same, but google analytics will have better support for them than custom variables in the future.

Here's a guide about how to set up a new dimension:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en

Specifically addressing your problem, you need to define a new custom dimension which will be called or example 'ContactFormCategory', and set its scope to be 'hit' (since this dimension should be associated with your following event only) and GA will assign an index to that dimension. Let's assume that index equals 1.

Then the code you'll put will be:

```
$('#contact-site-form').submit(function() {
    ga.('set', { 'dimension1': 'your_category_value' });
    ga.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact Form', 'Form submission', 'New submission']);
});
```

If for some reason you can't upgrade to universal analytics and you're stuck with classic analytics, you can only use custom variables. You won't need to define anything in the analytics UI like in dimensions\metrics, only to set the appropriate data. You can use this guide to do it:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables